# Why does -O3 cause this?

Tags: gcc, assembly

I found [this nice tool](http://gcc.godbolt.org/) that lets you compare code generated by different compilers. Now, take a look at this piece of code:

```
001    int testFunction(int* input, int length) {
002      int sum = 0;
003      for (int i = 0; i < length; ++i) {
004        sum += input[i];
005      }
006      return sum;
007    }
```

These 24 lines are the output from gcc with no optimization flags:

```
001    testFunction(int*, int):
002        pushq    %rbp
003        movq    %rsp, %rbp
004        movq    %rdi, -24(%rbp)
005        movl    %esi, -28(%rbp)
006        movl    $0, -8(%rbp)
007        movl    $0, -4(%rbp)
008        jmp    .L2
009    .L3:
010        movl    -4(%rbp), %eax
011        cltq
012        leaq    0(,%rax,4), %rdx
013        movq    -24(%rbp), %rax
014        addq    %rdx, %rax
015        movl    (%rax), %eax
016        addl    %eax, -8(%rbp)
017        addl    $1, -4(%rbp)
018    .L2:
019        movl    -4(%rbp), %eax
020        cmpl    -28(%rbp), %eax
021        jl    .L3
022        movl    -8(%rbp), %eax
023        popq    %rbp
024        ret
```

These nice 14 lines are the output from gcc with `-O2` flag:

```
001    testFunction(int*, int):
002        testl    %esi, %esi
003        jle    .L4
004        xorl    %edx, %edx
005        xorl    %eax, %eax
006    .L3:
007        addl    (%rdi,%rdx,4), %eax
008        addq    $1, %rdx
009        cmpl    %edx, %esi
010        jg    .L3
011        rep; ret
012    .L4:
013        xorl    %eax, %eax
014        ret
```

And these 122 lines are the output with `-O3` flag:

```
001    testFunction(int*, int):
002        testl    %esi, %esi
003        jle    .L14
004        movq    %rdi, %rax
005        movl    %esi, %edx
006        andl    $15, %eax
007        shrq    $2, %rax
008        negq    %rax
009        andl    $3, %eax
010        cmpl    %esi, %eax
011        cmova    %esi, %eax
012        cmpl    $8, %esi
013        ja    .L29
014    .L3:
015        cmpl    $1, %edx
016        movl    (%rdi), %eax
017        jbe    .L17
018        addl    4(%rdi), %eax
019        cmpl    $2, %edx
020        jbe    .L18
021        addl    8(%rdi), %eax
022        cmpl    $3, %edx
023        jbe    .L19
024        addl    12(%rdi), %eax
025        cmpl    $4, %edx
026        jbe    .L20
027        addl    16(%rdi), %eax
028        cmpl    $5, %edx
029        jbe    .L21
030        addl    20(%rdi), %eax
031        cmpl    $6, %edx
032        jbe    .L22
033        addl    24(%rdi), %eax
034        cmpl    $7, %edx
035        jbe    .L23
036        addl    28(%rdi), %eax
037        movl    $8, %ecx
038    .L5:
039        cmpl    %edx, %esi
040        je    .L30
041    .L4:
042        movl    %esi, %r11d
043        movl    %edx, %r8d
044        subl    %edx, %r11d
045        movl    %r11d, %r9d
046        shrl    $2, %r9d
047        leal    0(,%r9,4), %r10d
048        testl    %r10d, %r10d
049        je    .L7
050        pxor    %xmm0, %xmm0
051        leaq    (%rdi,%r8,4), %r8
052        xorl    %edx, %edx
053    .L13:
054        addl    $1, %edx
055        paddd    (%r8), %xmm0
056        addq    $16, %r8
057        cmpl    %edx, %r9d
058        ja    .L13
059        movdqa    %xmm0, %xmm2
060        addl    %r10d, %ecx
061        psrldq    $8, %xmm2
062        paddd    %xmm2, %xmm0
063        movdqa    %xmm0, %xmm3
064        psrldq    $4, %xmm3
065        paddd    %xmm3, %xmm0
066        movd    %xmm0, -12(%rsp)
067        addl    -12(%rsp), %eax
068        cmpl    %r10d, %r11d
069        je    .L2
070    .L7:
071        movslq    %ecx, %rdx
072        addl    (%rdi,%rdx,4), %eax
073        leal    1(%rcx), %edx
074        cmpl    %edx, %esi
075        jle    .L2
076        movslq    %edx, %rdx
077        addl    $2, %ecx
078        addl    (%rdi,%rdx,4), %eax
079        cmpl    %ecx, %esi
080        jle    .L31
081        movslq    %ecx, %rcx
082        addl    (%rdi,%rcx,4), %eax
083        ret
084    .L14:
085        xorl    %eax, %eax
086    .L2:
087        rep; ret
088    .L30:
089        rep; ret
090    .L29:
091        testl    %eax, %eax
092        jne    .L32
093        xorl    %edx, %edx
094        xorl    %ecx, %ecx
095        xorl    %eax, %eax
096        jmp    .L4
097    .L31:
098        rep; ret
099    .L18:
100        movl    $2, %ecx
101        jmp    .L5
102    .L23:
103        movl    $7, %ecx
104        jmp    .L5
105    .L17:
106        movl    $1, %ecx
107        jmp    .L5
108    .L19:
109        movl    $3, %ecx
110        jmp    .L5
111    .L20:
112        movl    $4, %ecx
113        jmp    .L5
114    .L21:
115        movl    $5, %ecx
116        jmp    .L5
117    .L22:
118        movl    $6, %ecx
119        jmp    .L5
120    .L32:
121        movl    %eax, %edx
122        jmp    .L3
```

Clang behaves similarly too.

Am I missing something? I thought -O3 was a higher level of optimization? Is that optimized?

Comment: It's called [loop unrolling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loop_unwinding). Looks like it also [vectorized](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vectorization_%28parallel_computing%29) it as well.

Comment: Less code does not necessarily equal faster/more optimized.

Comment: There's often a tradeoff between compiling for code size vs. compiling for speed. Some compilers will have an option letting you specify one or the other.

Comment: -1 for not explaining why you believe that the presented code has problems or how your expectations differ, and for not performing any benchmarks, and for not reading up on the instructions emitted in the O3 version.

Comment: to have it produced less code, use [Os](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Optimize-Options.html)

Comment: @KerrekSB I'm just asking "Is that optimized?", no need to be rude.. And I did try to read those instructions, but it looks like an overly complicated way to do something simple. I'm reading about loop unrolling and vectorization now.

Comment: @izabera: Sorry if it came across rude, but all I'm saying is that this isn't a very useful question the way it's phrased, which is what the score reflects. You're just saying "here's some code, I don't understand", without explaining your expectations and what specifically you don't understand. It makes the question hard to answer, and also unlikely to be useful to anyone else (think about whether this would be findable by someone searching for a similar topic).